# DataImport is Processing 867677 records added only 850789 records. Missing only when the record set is >800000

Tags: solr, dih

I have configured a SOLR core where the DB config will connect to oracle and get the records.

The total unique records with grouping on all of the columns is 854,076.

But when I execute `*:*` on the same core there are 100 to 220 records missing every time.

I have tried to increase:

```
solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets 1000000
solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime 100
solr.autoCommit.maxTime 500

<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
    <bool name="overwriteDupes">false</bool>
    <str name="signatureField">UUID</str>
    <str name="signatureClass">org.apache.solr.update.processor.TextProfileSignature</str>
</processor>
```

All the records are unique because we have the Grouping in the query. It can't be duplicate at all.

If there are 854,076 why not same number available in the numOfFound in the core when I query using `*:*`.

We have the unique field as `UUID` and its generated based on all of the column value.

Comment: What happens if you disable the update processor and use your _actual unique field_ as the unique key? There is no need to use the UUID format if you already have a unique key. It'll also allow you to find the actual missing rows if they're still missing after re-importing.

Comment: The problem is i dont have a actual unique field on the document so i have to generate one and also am using this field for few more logics in subsequent program so disabling this is not an option.

Comment: OK - but be aware that TextProfileSignature will not make any unique row get a unique id - it's [a fuzzy hash that drops certain tokens based on their frequency](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/TextProfileSignature) etc. It also considers only the bag of words, ignoring any word order. Depending on your content, it's perfectly probable that it will generate duplicate ids. Since you're talking about using grouping to get unique rows, consider using your group criteria to create an actual unique id instead.

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank you from the bottom of my hearts for helping me out here and actively responding. Now I have made the signature class to use lookup3 and certain other changes like maxCommit time to 500 and softCommit to 100 milliseconds. It seems to be fetching all the records but am still scared of performance now.

Comment: Those commit times are really low; you probably want to make them way larger unless you have a very particular reason to keep them low.

Comment: It was mainly Because it was missing records and my first doubt was towards commit. And now since it has fixed the issues I believe it was because of commit.am not seeing any performance lags as of now yet. Will keep checking